# Progress dialog in async task is not shown anymore after screen rotation

Tags: android

I am using an async task for uploading pictures to a remote server. To show the progress to the user I am using a progress dialog. This progress dialog is created at the preExecute method of the async task class.

When the user rotates the screen, the progress dialog disappears but the async task is still running. The activity holds a static reference to the async task so I do know that the task is still running. How can I now show up the progress dialog again? I tried the following:

The create method of the activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

if(task != null) {
Status status = task.getStatus();

if(status == Status.RUNNING) {
    task.updateViewContext(this);
}

}
```

the constructor of my async task class:

```
public UploadTask(UploadPicturesActivity activity) {
   this.context = activity;
   dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
   dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);        
}
```

the preexcetue method of my asnyc task class:

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
     this.dialog.show();
}
```

and trying to show the dialog again (does not work):

```
public void updateViewContext(UploadPicturesActivity activity) {
    this.context = activity;
    dialog.show();
}
```

Regards

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Android destroys your activity and restarts it on rotation.  This means all views, dialogs, etc are destroyed.  But a running thread can't be.  The best solution for this is to add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to your activity in the manifest, this will turn off this behavior for your activity.  It will still redraw your activity correctly though, so long as you don't have different layouts for landscape and portrait.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you add attribute `android:configChanges="orientation"` to the activity declaration in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

The purpose of the `android:configChanges` attribute is to prevent an activity from being recreated when it's really required.

It won't dismiss dialog when `screen orientation` changes.

```
Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "screen size" also changes when the device 
switches between portrait and landscape orientation. Thus, if you want to prevent runtime 
restarts due to orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher (as declared by the 
minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you must include the "screenSize" value in 
addition to the "orientation" value.That is, you must declare android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```